# reCAPTCHA keep saying incorrect-captcha-sol

Tags: recaptcha

I have this form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1"> 
    <tr> 
<td width="32%" valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="main_title">Select Category: </strong></td> 
<td width="68%" valign="top" class=""><?            $qu="SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `linkvideos_category` WHERE `status` = '1'";           $rs=$Q($qu);            ?> 
<select name="category" class="blacktext" > 
<option>Choose Category</option> 
<?          while($dis=$F($rs))         {           ?> 
<option value="<?=$dis['id']?>"> <?=$dis['name'];?></option> 
<? } ?> 
</select></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="main_title">Upload Image: </strong></td> 
<td valign="top" class=""><input type="file" name="imagefile" /> </td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="main_title"> Your Link : </strong></td> 
<td valign="top" class=""><input name="link" type="text" size="50" /></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="main_title"> Link Title : </strong></td> 
<td valign="top" class=""><input name="linkname" type="text" size="50" /></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="main_title">Description:</strong></td> 
<td valign="top"><label> 
<textarea name="desc" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea> 
</label></td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td valign="top">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong class="main_title">Security Code:</strong></td> 
<td valign="top">
<? if ($error==3) { ?>
<font color="red">Invalid Code Entered</font>
<?}?>
<?php
require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
echo recaptcha_get_html($public_key);
?></td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td colspan="2" valign="top" class="">&nbsp;</td> 
</tr>  


<tr> 
<td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top" class=""><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="btns"  onclick="javascript:return check();" /></td> 
</tr> 
</form>
```

and i'm verifying the captcha with this

```
     $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_key,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
$error = 3;
 echo"<script>window.location='submit_linkvideo.php?error=3';</script>";
}
```

and every time it's telling me the captchas invalid and saying incorrect-captcha-sol, am I missing something? I've tested it and the recaptcha values arn't being submitted.

Comment: Your HTML/PHP snippet does not show you ever setting $public_key which is required for recaptcha_get_html to generate the correct HTML.  I presume you set it to the correct value somewhere previous to your snippet.  I presume also you are testing this from the actual domain the key is valid for, and not from a localhost test server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by ending a table before the form then starting the table again once inside the form.